# Is there a faster way to run sapply that is nested in two for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I have a big data frame with > 1 million lines representing time series data for several individuals (with different individual data in different columns). 
In addition, I have a 3D array that contains encounter frame numbers that indicate from which frame in my time series I want to extract data.

For a given individual and encounter type, I want to extract one time series of e.g. 100 frames. However, as I have many replicates for each meeting type and each individual, I want to directly calculate the average time series per individual and encounter type.

I managed to do so using sapply embedded in two for loops. However, running these for loops is very slow, and I now wonder whether there is a faster way of implementing this calculation in R, or whether I should rather do it in C++. Below my code, and the small bit of my data:

```
nb_ind = 3;
response_duration = 100;
nb_meeting_types = 2;
nb_variables = 2;
speed_offset = 2;
MEETING_START_OFFSET = 50;
replicate = 20;

# behavior_data is a data frame with columns: frame,speed1,head1,speed2,head2,speed3,head3
# there are about 1 million rows
dim(behavior_data)
[1] 1080000  7

head(behavior_data)
  frame speed1 head1 speed2 headd2 speed3 head3 
1  0      0     25    2.4   179     1.1   16
2  1      1.5   20    2.0   -175    1.6   27
3  2      1.6   28    2.0   -178    1.0   37
4  3      0.8   56    1.6   170     0.8   37
5  4      0.3   56    1.8   162     0     40

# encounters is an array with frame numbers of dimension [nb_ind,replicate,nb_meeting_types]
# these frame number correspond to starting points of meetings, for which I want to calculate the speed    
dim(encounters)
[1] 3 20  2

head(encounters[,,1])
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]  [,11] [,12]  [,13]  [,14] [,15]  [,16] [,17]  [,18]  [,19] [,20]
[1,] 12049 17693 23350 29018 34666 40327 68608 57293 74264 45980 113864 79922 119522 102552 51636 153462 91235 142151 159121 62948
[2,] 12036 17694 23352 29014 34674 40322 68606 57296 74268 45982 113865 79929 119521 102558 51639 153463 91242 142161 159168 62952
[3,] 12037 17694 23351 29011 34669 40329 68606 57298 74263 45985     NA 79921     NA 102550 51641     NA 91234     NA     NA 62950


all_average_speeds = array(NaN, c(nb_ind, response_duration, nb_meeting_types))
for (j in 1:nb_ind){

  #calculate the average speed response for each meeting type for a given individual
  average_speed = numeric(0);
  for (i in 1:nb_meeting_types){

    # calculate the average speed response across all replicates of a given meeting type for a given individual
average_speed_type = sapply(1:response_duration, function(k){
      mean(behavior_data[,(j-1)*nb_variables + speed_offset][which(behavior_data$frame == ((encounters[j,,i] + k-1) - MEETING_START_OFFSET)], na.rm=TRUE)
    })
    average_speed = rbind(average_speed, t(average_speed_type))
  }
  all_average_speeds[j,,] = average_speed; 
}
```

Comment: Form a first look at it, I stumble upon the rbind within the inner loop. That is generally a bad idea. Try to allocate all the memory and all the colums and rows that average_speed will have in advance (find something better than `average_speed = numeric(0);`) and see, if that speeds up enough. Only if not, touch the working loops.   If you need to chance something about the loops, try the `foreach` loop in the `foreach`package for the outer loop. It makes it really easy to go from `for` loop to parallel processing.

Comment: please include a dataset that the code works on - either change your numbers so that it matches, or put a larger part on here. It may be possible to fully vectorise this, the otehr quick speedup I can see if is the 'frame' column equals the row number, you can replace the sapply with a subset by position.

Comment: @ Bernhard. As suggested I replaced `average_speed = numeric(0);` with a preallocated array filled with NaN but in terms of execution time there is no difference. For part of my dataset (15 individuals, time series with 1090504 frames, response duration of 1200 frames, 5 meeting types) the times are 23.91min when I use numeric, and 23.94min when I use a preallocated array.

Comment: @jeremycg. I don't understand your suggestion about using subset. Can you provide more details please. For info, the frame number does not always equal the row number, but as the frames numbers are sequential and increasing, an offset should be able to account for a difference. Also, my data set seems too big (450MB) to be uploaded here.

Comment: To further add to the performance issue, I tested the code by adding another sapply in the nested for loops, and the time needed to execute the code then doubles suggesting that it is the sapply itself that consumes the time. If I run sapply by itself, i.e. by setting i=1 and j=1, then it takes about 4.28min. Is there a more efficient way to write the sapply function than the way I chose?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say the sapply by itself (with i=1 and j=1) runs in 20.4sec, which when repeated 5*15 times adds up the ~25min reported before.